# I do not have WordPress at site root and want two sub-directories implemented with single wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, multisite

I have CakePHP at the root of my website (`http://example.com`). And I want single WordPress installation for two subdirectories of my site:

```
http://example.com/blog
http://example.com/store
```

I know there is multisite concept in WordPress but I think it works only if I have WordPress at the root of my site (`http://example.com`).

I searched a lot but I have not found any solution yet. Can it achieve through `.htaccess` of CakePHP website which exist as main website? Or there are any other possibilities?